# can address be typecasted?

Tags: c

I want the address of structure, but in my code I am only able to return the address of value the first member. Can I typecast the address of value to struct classifier? If yes how to type cast it ? For example, my function only returns the address of `value` in the below mentioned `struct` can I cast this address to `classifier`?

```
    struct classifier
    {
        int value;
        struct packet_filter pktFltr;
        struct classifier *next;
    }
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question, it's not really understandable if you want to get value of next or memory address of it.

Comment: Can you please try and improve your punctuation? Thanks

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check whether this what you wanted to ask.

Comment: @Naveen:yes this is what i wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard states that the address of a structure `classifier` is the same as the address of its first member `value` provided that you are casting it correctly.

That is, following is equivalent, p points to the same address :

```
int *p;
struct classifier c;

p = (int*)c;
p = &c.value;
```

Meaning that

```
(int*) c == &c.value
```

And in your case, if I understand it correctly you would want:

```
c = (struct chassifier *) adress_of_my_first_member_in_struct_classifier;
```

Comment: in my code i have done this return(&ptr->keys[pos].value); but the return type of function is struct classifier *search(int key), i get a error: conflicting types for 'search'. how to type cast int address to struct classifier address, as i need struct classifier address only

Comment: @asir: As stated in the answer, you can use `return((struct chassifier *)(&ptr->keys[pos].value);` BTW why don't you do `return &ptr->keys[pos];`?

Answer (score 0):

While it is guaranteed that the first member of struct will have the same address as struct itself (as padding is not permitted in the beginning), casting the return value of an `int* function()` to `some_struct*` is not a good practice - what if someone later decides to modify the function to return the address of some malloc'ed int instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an object of type `struct classifier`, the address of that object is of type `struct classifier *`. There is nothing special about it ...

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct classifier {
    int value;
    struct packet_filter pktFltr;
    struct classifier *next;
};

void foo(struct classifier *bar) {
    printf("value is %d\n", bar->value);
}

int main(void) {
    struct classifier example = {42}; /* value is 42, everything else is 0  */
    foo(&example); /* ok, `&example` is of the correct type */
    return 0;
}
```